# Rounding a field's value in a SELECT statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, code-behind

What I need to do is to round a field to 2 decimals, but not in the usual way.  I have a dropdown that's always rounded to 2 decimals (CIT_NBR).  However, in the database table, it's sometimes rounded to 1 decimal.  So now I'm trying to create a SELECT statement based on this field, but my front end stores it as 2 decimals and my back end can be stored as either 1 or 2 decimals.  Don't ask, it's complicated.  :o)

So, what I want to do in "aircode" is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM VW_MOS_DPL_AccountValidation WHERE CUST_NUM = @CNum 
   AND Format(CIT_NBR, 2 decimals) = @CITNum
```

This way, it forces the data in the table to use 2 decimals, so it can be compared to my dropdown.

Here's my code block:

```
using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(str2))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM VW_MOS_DPL_AccountValidation WHERE CUST_NUM = @CNum AND CIT_NBR = @CITNum", con2))
    {
        con2.Open();

        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CNum", TBAccountNum.Text);

        string ddlCITVal2 = ddlCIT.SelectedValue;
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CITNum", ddlCITVal2);

        using (SqlDataReader DT2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // If the SQL returns any records, process the info
            if (DT2.HasRows)
            {
                while (DT2.Read())
                {
.
.
.
etc
```

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: does SQL have a Round() function..? have you tried that..? I don't see it anywhere in your Select Statement.. do a simple google search for how to use `Round() inside of a Select Statement`

Comment: Is the field in the database a number or a string? If it is a number, you don't have to add anything, right? `1 == 1.0000000`

Comment: It's a string.  So, in the database I'm getting "11.0" and on the front end it's "11.00".  When I try to run the SELECT statement, it's not seeing them as equal and returns no records.

Comment: perhaps you need to change the datatype in the database to be a Decimal 8,2 for example or use the decimal representation of the string and or format the string.. sounds pretty straight forward to me if you know sql then you can do the following and Cast the varchar to a decimal 
`SELECT SUM(Cast(CitNum as decimal(8,2))) as CitNum FROM table`

Comment: The problem is, it's not really a number.  It's like a version number.  Sometimes it's 1.0, sometimes it's 1.37.  It can have either 1 or 2 decimals.  It's not *really* a version number, but that's the best comparison I can make.  I can't change the datatype.

Comment: More example data would really help.

Comment: @MethodMan - Your CAST() worked.  If you want to put it as an answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem I will add it right now.. Glad I could quickly provide you with a working start and or solution @JohnnyBones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cast the varchar to a decimal`

```
SELECT SUM(Cast(CitNum as decimal(8,2))) as CitNum FROM table
```

Comment: Had to change it slightly to "SELECT * FROM VW_MOS_DPL_AccountValidation WHERE CUST_NUM = @CNum AND Cast(CIT_NBR as decimal(5,2)) = @CITNum", but it worked great.  Thanks!

Comment: yeah I was using `8,2` as an example to depict the decimal , precision cheers..!

Answer (score 0):

There is a more performant approach, but this is easiest to read and maintain unless it causes a real performance problem.

```
SELECT * 
FROM VW_MOS_DPL_AccountValidation 
WHERE CUST_NUM = @CNum 
  AND (CIT_NBR=@CITNUM OR CIT_NBR+'0'=@CITNUM)
```

Unless you really meant rounded to one decimal instead of the example you gave which is just truncating a trailing zero, in which case a different approach would need to be used.